# Broken pipe after trying to install NodeJS 14

Tags: node.js

I am trying to install the latest nodejs pkg (14.17.x). I got the error:

> dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe) .

Now, I am not able to do update and install pkg command, I'm getting the following error:

> ( dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe) ; when trying ((
> kali@kali:~$ sudo apt update
> kali@kali:~$
> kali@kali:~$ sudo apt full-upgrade -y
> kali@kali:~$
> )
>
> dpkg: error processing archive  /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_14.17.1-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
> trying to overwrite '/usr/share/doc/nodejs/api/punycode.md', which is also in package nodejs-doc 12.21.0~dfsg-4
> dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)

Can you help?

Comment: FYI, the latest version of NodeJS is currently 16.3.0. and 14.17.1 is the Long Term Support (LTS) version.

Answer (score 15):

trying to overwrite `/usr/share/doc/nodejs/api/punycode.md`, which is also in package `nodejs-doc 12.21.0~dfsg-4`

command: `dpkg -l | grep node`

result like this: `ii  nodejs-doc    12.21.0~dfsg-3  all   API documentation fo...`

then command: `dpkg -r nodejs-doc`

then command: `curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash -`

`apt-get install -y nodejs`

well done! The problem is solved!

Comment: Hi. Could you please format your code with code blocks? You can refer to the [help section on formatting posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 9):

in my case `apt autoremove` solved the issue by removing a long list of node-xxxx :

```
Removing node-abbrev (1.1.1+~1.1.2-1) ...
Removing node-ansi-regex (5.0.1-1) ...
Removing node-slice-ansi (5.0.0+~cs9.0.0-4) ...
Removing node-ansi-styles (4.3.0+~4.2.0-1) ...
Removing node-ansistyles (0.1.3-5) ...
Removing node-minimist (1.2.5+~cs5.3.2-1) ...
Removing node-arrify (2.0.1-2) ...
Removing node-asap (2.0.6+~2.0.0-1) ...
Removing node-asynckit (0.4.0-4) ...
Removing node-minimatch (3.1.1+~3.0.5-1) ...
Removing node-brace-expansion (2.0.1-1) ...
Removing node-balanced-match (2.0.0-1) ...
Removing node-chownr (2.0.0-1) ...
Removing node-clean-yaml-object (0.1.0-5) ...
Removing node-color-convert (2.0.1-1) ...
Removing node-color-name (1.1.4+~1.1.1-2) ...
Removing node-commander (9.0.0-2) ...
Removing node-core-util-is (1.0.3-1) ...
Removing node-decompress-response (6.0.0-2) ...
Removing node-delayed-stream (1.0.0-5) ...
Removing node-delegates (1.0.0-3) ...
Removing node-depd (2.0.0-2) ...
Removing node-diff (5.0.0~dfsg+~5.0.1-3) ...
Removing node-minipass (3.1.6+~cs8.7.18-1) ...
Removing node-encoding (0.1.13-2) ...
Removing node-get-stream (6.0.1-1) ...
Removing node-pump (3.0.0-5) ...
Removing node-end-of-stream (1.4.4+~1.4.1-1) ...
Removing node-promise-retry (2.0.1-2) ...
Removing node-err-code (2.0.3+dfsg-3) ...
Removing node-p-map (4.0.0+~3.1.0+~3.0.1-1) ...
Removing node-escape-string-regexp (4.0.0-2) ...
Removing node-fancy-log (1.3.3+~cs1.3.1-2) ...
Removing node-foreground-child (2.0.0-3) ...
Removing node-fs.realpath (1.0.0-2) ...
Removing node-resolve (1.20.0+~cs5.27.9-1) ...
Removing node-function-bind (1.1.1+repacked+~1.0.3-1) ...
Removing node-growl (1.10.5-4) ...
Removing node-supports-color (8.1.1+~8.1.1-1) ...
Removing node-has-flag (4.0.0-2) ...
Removing node-has-unicode (2.0.1-4) ...
Removing node-hosted-git-info (4.0.2-1) ...
Removing node-iconv-lite (0.6.3-2) ...
Removing node-iferr (1.0.2+~1.0.2-1) ...
Removing node-imurmurhash (0.1.4+dfsg+~0.1.1-1) ...
Removing node-indent-string (4.0.0-2) ...
Removing node-inflight (1.0.6-2) ...
Removing node-ini (2.0.1-1) ...
Removing node-ip (1.1.5+~1.1.0-1) ...
Removing node-ip-regex (4.3.0+~4.1.1-1) ...
Removing node-kind-of (6.0.3+dfsg-2) ...
Removing node-is-buffer (2.0.5-2) ...
Removing node-is-plain-obj (3.0.0-2) ...
Removing node-isarray (2.0.5-3) ...
Removing node-isexe (2.0.0+~2.0.1-4) ...
Removing node-json-parse-better-errors (1.0.2+~cs3.3.1-1) ...
Removing node-jsonparse (1.3.1-10) ...
Removing node-lodash-packages (4.17.21+dfsg+~cs8.31.198.20210220-5) ...
Removing node-lowercase-keys (2.0.0-2) ...
Removing node-lru-cache (6.0.0+~5.1.1-1) ...
Removing node-mimic-response (3.1.0-7) ...
Removing node-promzard (0.3.0-2) ...
Removing node-read (1.0.7-3) ...
Removing node-mute-stream (0.0.8+~0.0.1-1) ...
Removing node-negotiator (0.6.2+~0.6.1-1) ...
Removing node-npm-bundled (1.1.2-1) ...
Removing node-once (1.4.0-4) ...
Removing node-osenv (0.1.5+~0.1.0-1) ...
Removing node-p-cancelable (2.1.1-1) ...
Removing node-path-is-absolute (2.0.0-2) ...
Removing node-process-nextick-args (2.0.1-2) ...
Removing node-promise-inflight (1.0.1+~1.0.0-1) ...
Removing node-quick-lru (5.1.1-1) ...
Removing node-retry (0.13.1+~0.12.1-1) ...
Removing node-string-decoder (1.3.0-5) ...
Removing node-safe-buffer (5.2.1+~cs2.1.2-2) ...
Removing node-set-blocking (2.0.0-2) ...
Removing node-signal-exit (3.0.6+~3.0.1-1) ...
Removing node-slash (3.0.0-2) ...
Removing node-validate-npm-package-license (3.0.4-2) ...
Removing node-spdx-correct (3.1.1-2) ...
Removing node-spdx-expression-parse (3.0.1+~3.0.1-1) ...
Removing node-spdx-exceptions (2.3.0-2) ...
Removing node-spdx-license-ids (3.0.11-1) ...
Removing node-stealthy-require (1.1.1-5) ...
Removing node-text-table (0.2.0-4) ...
Removing node-time-stamp (2.2.0-1) ...
Removing node-tmatch (5.0.0-4) ...
Removing node-universalify (2.0.0-3) ...
Removing node-util-deprecate (1.0.2-3) ...
Removing node-webidl-conversions (7.0.0~1.1.0+~cs15.1.20180823-2) ...
Removing node-whatwg-fetch (3.6.2-5) ...
Removing node-wrappy (1.0.2-2) ...
Removing node-yallist (4.0.0+~4.0.1-1) ...
```

then `apt install nodejs` worked like a charm

Answer (score 4):

Run a verification on each node to check if the installation was successful:

```
dpkg -l | grep node
```

Then delete nodejs-doc:

```
dpkg -r nodejs-doc
```

Next add the latest node repository to linuxin my case its (14).

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo -E bash -
```

Run a system update:

```
sudo apt update
```

You can now install node:

```
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

NB:If you dont want to use sudo for security reasons,you can do this the hard way-:By creating a temp directory,cd into,download node package onto your system and make the package executable,then install it.

Perform another system update:

```
sudo apt update
```

You should be able to now check your npm and node versions after this process.

```
node -v
npm -v
```

[node and np versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EMH5.png)

Answer (score 1):

On newer NodeJS Version like 18.X.X something do this instead
works on my side:
`dpkg -l | grep node`
then remove all node version instances you see that has an X.X version
For example, the `libnode-dev` instance
just do:
`sudo dpkg -r libnode-dev`
`sudo dpkg -r libnode72:amd64`

Answer (score 0):

i'm on Mint, but my nodejs is also not working.
Using `apt list` command:
the output for nodejs is "unknown":

nodejs/unknown,now 14.17.1-deb-1nodesource1 amd64 [installed]

Working software displays like this in the `apt list` command:

node-split/focal,focal 1.0.0-1 all

May be related to your problem.

Try running `apt list |  grep unknown` to see if "unknown" pops up.